# Find id of TR when button is clicked in TD using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Looking to find a way to get a unique identifier to pass as a parameter to a function in javascript. Wanting to get the id of the first td if possible

```
<tr id='it'><td id="#nameiron">Jason</td><td id="#priceiron">sss</td><td><button id="#namebutttt">Buy</button></td><td><button>Sell</button></td></tr>
<tr ><td id="#namecolbolt">Jason</td><td id="#pricecolbolt">sss</td><td><button>Buy</button></td><td><button>Sell</button></td></tr>
<tr ><td id="#namealuminium">Jason</td><td id="#pricealuminium">sss</td><td><button>Buy</button></td><td><button>Sell</button></td></tr>
<tr ><td id="#namenickel">Jason</td><td id="#pricenickel">sss</td><td><button>Buy</button></td><td><button>Sell</button></td></tr>
<tr ><td id="#namesilver">Jason</td><td id="#pricesilver">sss</td><td><button>Buy</button></td><td><button>Sell</button></td></tr>
<tr ><td id="#namegold">Jason</td><td id="#pricegold">sss</td><td><button>Buy</button></td><td><button>Sell</button></td></tr>
<tr ><td id="#nameosmium">Jason</td><td id="#priceosmium">sss</td><td><button>Buy</button></td><td><button>Sell</button></td></tr>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) is the key to finding a specific ancestor elements (parent, grandparent, etc). Unlike `parents` it returns the first matching ancestor:

```
$('td button').click(function(){
    alert($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
    alert($(this).closest('tr').find('td:first').attr('id'));
});
```

Note: It is not clear what you want to do with the values, but in practice you would avoid re-running the same selectors (use local vars to hold selector results):

```
$('td button').click(function(){
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    alert($tr.attr('id'));
    alert($tr.find('td:first').attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Ok thanks :)  i was using the :button selector :S thanks mate :)

Comment: @cloudsmurf: yes, saw that and updated already.

Comment: Your a champ mate, thanks

Comment: Basically I want to use the button to grab an unique identifier that corresponds to item in array.